# angular ng-repeat over TR does not allow template directives?

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive

Use case is have a table and iterate over rows. Each row should be expanded from the template using a directive

**html**

```
<tr ng-repeat='t in data'>
  <stats stat="t"></stats>
</tr>
```

(The fragment above does not render a anything at all)

**directive**

```
app.directive('stats', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:  true,
        templateUrl: 'stats.html',
        scope: {
          stat: '='
        },
      };
});
```

Problem 1:
As long as ng-repeat defined over TR it does not work at all. Nothing happens. No iteration.

If I put ng-repeat in a div and move top TR tag into template it works but layout got screwed and no column formatting is preserved.

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat='t in data'>
  <stats stat="t"></stats>
</div>
```

(The fragment above does not render a correctly formatted table)

Comment: Have to use valid html structure. `<tr>` has limited allowed children tags . What does stats.html look like? What does data look like?

Answer (score 1):

Can put directive as attribute on row.

`<tr>` has specific allowed children like `<td>` or `<th>`

```
<tr ng-repeat='t in items' stats="t"></tr>
```

Directive using `template` that can be switched to `templateUrl`

```
app.directive('stats', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:'<td ng-repeat="item in t">{{item}}</td>'
      };
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/LGSGfDSVBOat3HTQIPeQ?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. First solution worked. I changed directive a little bit by setting replace:  false and restrict: 'A'. So it worked with conjunction of appending attribute to TR element. It could be closed. Thank you very much!

Comment: `replace` is default `false` anyway ...and is also deprecated